# Check if Record Exists in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Could somebody please tell me how I check to see if a record exists, if it does exists then do nothing and if it doesn't then add the record to the database?

Please see my code below:

```
if (isIpnValidated == true)
{
    using (WebApplication1Entities db = new WebApplication1Entities())
    {
        Orders order = new Orders();
        order.UserId = userId;
        order.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
        order.Transaction = txnId;
        order.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(mcGross);
        order.Email = payerEmail;
        order.Country = residenceCountry;

        db.Orderss.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I just want to ensure no possible duplication in the database.

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate?

Comment: Apologies, I want to ensure the txnId does not already exist.

Comment: Your question is entirely unrelated to ASP.NET MVC. Your code looks like you were using Entity Framework though. Did you mean EF 5?

Comment: `if (db.Orderss.Any(o => o.Id == Id)) return;`

Comment: I cannot use Any with this function, I can use Find, Add, AddRange, etc... but not Any unfortunately.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 and if I type db.Orders. Any does not appear in the list and if I add it manually I get a red underline under the word Any.

Comment: @iggyweb Then you're missing a reference to `System.Linq`. Add it to the top of your file, or get Resharper ;)

Comment: @iggyweb Using sroes answer below, but you should start learning Linq syntax first.

Comment: Please refer this SO Answer[1].
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302244/check-if-a-record-exists-in-the-database/61420866#61420866

Comment: The naming convention "orderss" hurts my soul.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `Any`:

```
if (isIpnValidated)
{
    using (WebApplication1Entities db = new WebApplication1Entities())
    {
        if (db.Orderss.Any(o => o.Transaction == txnId)) return;

        Orders order = new Orders();
        order.UserId = userId;
        order.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
        order.Transaction = txnId;
        order.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(mcGross);
        order.Email = payerEmail;
        order.Country = residenceCountry;

        db.Orderss.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes he doesn't want to update an existing record...

Comment: Yes, see his question: "if it does exists then do nothing"

Comment: I definitely don't want to update, only add if the txnId does not exist.

Comment: Can I please ask one more thing, how do I check to see if a order actually exists for a user and todays date, I've tried `if (db.Orderss.Any(o => o.UserId == userId && o.Date == System.DateTime.Now)) return;` but it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: What about `if (db.Orderss.Any(o => o.UserId == userId && o.Date.Date == System.DateTime.Today)) return;`?

Comment: This is very bad. It can cause bugs if used concurrently!! Just think what happens if someone inserts an order like that between `Any` and `SaveChanges`. You will have 2 duplicate orders.

Answer (score 3):

```
using (WebApplication1Entities db = new WebApplication1Entities())
{
   var order = db.Orders.GetAll().Where(x=> x.Transaction == txnId).FirstOrDefault();
   if(order != null) // update
   {
      //.....
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
   else
   {
      // new
   }
}
```

Comment: No, since he is going to work with order, no need to run the statement twice.

Comment: Do you realize you just queried all the orders in the table when you only need one? There is no need for the GetAll()

Comment: Besides he is getting all columns , There is no need to FirstOrDefault either , just use count()