# Using post to update existing records in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sqlcommand, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm writing an API controller that inserts and updates records in a table. I'm able to insert new items into the database pretty easily, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to update existing records. My current solution is to query the number of records that have the same UserName and DeviceId as the request. If the count is > 0, then we execute the update query. Else, we execute the insert query. But I'm not sure how to return the count of records from the countQuery. Also, I would rather not use the patch or put methods for this. I want all the logic in the post method. Thanks for your help!

```
public BaseResponse Post([FromBody]PendingAttachmentRequest pending)
    {
        var datasource = "";
        var appVersion = "";
        var sessionId = "";
        var updateQuery = "UPDATE PendingAttachments SET PendingCount = @PendingCount,LastUpdated = @LastUpdated,DataSource = @DataSource WHERE DeviceId = @deviceId AND WHERE UserName = @userName";
        var countQuery = "SELECT count(*) PendingAttachments WHERE DeviceId = @DeviceId AND WHERE UserName = @UserName";
        MobileCompleteServer.Helpers.Connection.GetHeaderInfo(out sessionId, out datasource, out appVersion);
        using (var onbaseConnection = MobileCompleteServer.Helpers.Connection.Connect(sessionId, datasource))
        {
            var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(countQuery, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        if (/*how to check if the result of countQuery is > 0*/)
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, sqlConnection))
                            {
                                sqlComm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                                //replace that row with request body
                                sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DataSource", pending.DataSource));
                                sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdated", pending.LastUpdated));
                                sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PendingCount", pending.PendingCount));
                                sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DeviceId", pending.DeviceId));
                                sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", pending.UserName));
                            }
                        }
                        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertPendingAttachments", sqlConnection))
                        {
                            sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DataSource", pending.DataSource));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", pending.UserName));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DeviceId", pending.DeviceId));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PendingCount", pending.PendingCount));
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdated", pending.LastUpdated));
                            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    }
                }
                return new BaseResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message == Constants.SessionNotFound)
                {
                    return new BaseResponse
                    {
                        Exception = Constants.SessionNotFound,
                        ExceptionStackTrace = e.ToString()
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new BaseResponse
                    {
                        Exception = Constants.PendingAttachmentError,
                        ExceptionStackTrace = e.ToString()
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Technically, it is possible to update a record using POST. But in the world of REST this is heresy. Use PUT and PATCH. PUT to replace all values, PATCH to update certain values.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I want to use patch but on the client side I can only send post request because we don't know if the record exists at this point. How can I execute the patch method without sending a patch request from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about how many records are there and you just want to check whether at least a record exists or not in table, then use "exists". It will definitely improve query performance. So you need to only check for true or false condition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

You also need to use "ExecuteReader" / "ExecuteScalar" method: [Check if a record exists in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302244/check-if-a-record-exists-in-the-database)

Try to use Repository design pattern which will separate your data access logic and domain logic and it will also help in making your code testable. Also, Your method is doing lots of things at a time so its violating Single responsibility principle.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Quick question. Is there a difference in approach from using ExecuteScalar and ExecuteReader?

Comment: ExecuteScalar is a handy function when you want to just need one Cell value i.e. one column and one row.
What happens when we use ExecuteScalar for SELECT statement with multiple columns and multiple rows?:answer is yes we can use it but as its behavior it will return the very first cell i.e. first row and first column.

ExecuteReader is strictly used for fetching records from the SQL Query or Stored Procedure i.e. SELECT Operation.

In your case, if you use only "Exists" function that will improve your query and you can use executescalar.

Answer (score 1):

Do you not already have a method serving a `GET` endpoint taking `deviceId` and `userName` as parameters?  If not create it and call that method to check for existence and, depending on the result, you either call an `update` or `insert` handler.  That way your API will be more `RESTful` and modular thus less coupled to the business logic and more testable.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, are you saying I call the post and patch methods inside the get method?

Comment: Yes you could, however, ideally I'd take it a step further and create a repository class e.g. 'DBAttachmentsRepository' that has method like .Read(), .Insert(), .Update(), etc.  The controller methods should just call these methods instead of having the DB operation code sprinkled all over.  That way you can call myDBAttachmentsRepository.Read(deviceId, userName) from multiple controller methods.