# Records that need to be different

Tags: c#, sql, database, record

I am creating a database for a project. In this project there is a table called 'Bookings' this table has 2 fields called `DateOfBooking` (which is data type DateAndTime) and `TimeOfBooking` (which is data type DateAndTime also). In a UI form on the same project I have created a date and time picker that corresponds to the `DateOfBooking` field and a text box that corresponds to the `TimeOfBooking` field. For my system to be as robust as possible, I would like there to be no double bookings. So I need to  create a way to check that the specific dates and times haven't already been entered to the database. I can only find ways that allow for one field to be checked, which is not what I would like. I need to check both fields. Here is an attempt of what I have done:

```
//To Check that there is no double bookings
        

using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpsonsConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                sc.Open();
                SqlCommand commandToCheckDoubleBookings = new SqlCommand("SELECT DateOfBooking, TimeOfBooking FROM Bookings WHERE DateOfBooking= '" + dtp1.Text + "' AND TimeOfBooking= '" + txtTimeOfBooking.Text + "'", sc);
                string db = (string)commandToCheckDoubleBookings.ExecuteScalar();
                sc.Close();

                if(db == dtp1.Text )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This booking slot has already been taken, please choose another!");
                }
                else if(db ==)
            }
```

In this code, I am getting problems with the if statements, as they aren't checking the two fields at the same time. Only one field is being checked at a time. If there is any way you could help, it would be highly appreciated. If you need any extra info about the problem let me know! (My code is c#)

Comment: This is not a scalar query, so you should be using a dataset reader.

Comment: [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) _Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a record exists in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302244/check-if-a-record-exists-in-the-database)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could concatenate the values and compare the concatenated value 
The SQL would be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DateOfBooking, TimeOfBooking) FROM Bookings WHERE DateOfBooking= '" + dtp1.Text + "' AND TimeOfBooking= '" + txtTimeOfBooking.Text + "'"
```

Then your C# if statement would be:

```
if(db == dtp1.Text + txtTimeOfBooking.Text)
```

You just need to make sure the DateAndTime format returned from the database is the same as the format in the text from the form.